# Datagrid view sort on header click, using linq string comparer

Tags: c#, linq, columnsorting

Have a DataGridView on which I am trying to implement sorting on header click.
using linq I tried the following approach but unable to sort. Can you please guide me where It would have gone wrong

```
`       var param = DGV.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName;
        var propertyInfo = typeof(EditItem).GetProperty(param);

        IEnumerable<object> Items;
        Items= ObjectX.BindingList();

        if (so == SortOrder.Ascending)
        {                
            DGV.DataSource = Items.OrderBy(x => propertyInfo.GetValue(x, null) as String, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            DGV.DataSource = Items.OrderByDescending(x => propertyInfo.GetValue(x, null) as String, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).ToList();
        }

        grid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = so;`
```

Comment: Maybe `as String` returns `null` because it's not a string. You could use `ToString`

Comment: @TimSchmelter : Yes are right.ToString() worked perfecly.Thanks a million :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
if (so == SortOrder.Ascending)
{                
    DGV.DataSource = Items.OrderBy(x => propertyInfo.GetValue(x, null).ToString(), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).ToList();
}
else
{
    DGV.DataSource = Items.OrderByDescending(x => propertyInfo.GetValue(x, null).ToString(), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).ToList();
}
```

instead. If an object is unable to be cast to the type with a safe cast `as` statement, it will return null, which means it'll sort nothing.